# Evil mode - help with custom prefix key

Tags: key-bindings, evil, keyboard-macros

I had a custom key that I used extensively in Emacs for custom editing actions: `C-z`. I decided to use evil mode (I came from vim originally so nothing too new) but I don't know how to rebind evil's `C-z` to my `C-z`.

Should I just wrap the `global-set-key` calls that use `C-z` in a function that just takes a char with `interactive`? If I do that then I don't get the `F1 k C-z j g` functionality that shows me what `C-z j g` is bound to, which I use often (varying binds per mode).

Could I force the evil mode normal map `C-z` to use the global map `C-z`?